# Converting dictionary to Json?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to convert my dictionary to JSON. I have a client server application set and I'm trying to create an outgoing packet on the server side, but I have the packet data in a dictionary.

My dictionary structure is set up something like this.

```
"device.name" => "Machine-39FK394S"
"device.username" => "admin"
"device.operating_system" => "Windows 10"
"something.else" => 294
```

A dot represents another level in JSON, the output in JSON would be like this.

```
{
    "device" : {
        "name" : "Machine-39FK394S",
        "username" : "admin",
        "operating_system" : "Windows 10",
    }

    "something" : {
        "else" : 294,
    }
}
```

What have I tried so far?

```
public string GetJson()
{
    var entries = _packetData.Select(d => string.Format("\"{0}\": [{1}]", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
    return "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
}
```

Although the above method just outputs an empty `{}` json string.

Comment: use NewtonSoft.JSON - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Trying to do this without dependencies if I can, also I need to do it in a generic way, I won't always know the values of this dictionary.

Comment: seegal it's not really a dependency. It's a core reference. Take a look at msdn, sentence 1 of the "old" way - JavaScriptSerializer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx ... It's available under Assemblies in "Add reference" .. you don't download a 3rd party - it's built in

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this, it should work for any number of properties:

```
var inputDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

inputDict["device.name"] = "Machine-39FK394S";
inputDict["device.username"] = "admin";
inputDict["device.operating_system"] = "Windows 10";
inputDict["something.else"] = 294;

var outputObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var kvp in inputDict)
{
    var currentDict = outputObject;
    var depth = 0;
    var fields = kvp.Key.Split('.');

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if (++depth == fields.Length)
        {
            currentDict[field] = kvp.Value;
        }
        else if (!currentDict.ContainsKey(field))
        {
            currentDict[field] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
        currentDict = currentDict[field] as Dictionary<string, object>;
    }
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outputObject, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine("JSON: " + json);
```

I get the output below:

```
{
  "device": {
    "name": "Machine-39FK394S",
    "username": "admin",
    "operating_system": "Windows 10"
  },
  "something": {
    "else": 294
  }
}
```

This uses Newtonsoft Json.Net, however I do believe it would be hard to compose this JSON without such a library. Json.Net will handle all the conversion of various types of objects to string, plus it will handle escaping JSON delimiters. Writing this type of code yourself will be very nasty. In addition it's highly customizable and will allow datetime formats etc. to be changed.

You might need a little refinement to handle NULLs etc.

If you wish to avoid using Json.Net, you can add a reference to System.Web.Extensions and like so:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(outputObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet to do that. ie:

```
var data = new 
{
    device = new 
    {
        name = "Machine-39FK394S",
        username = "admin",
        operating_system = "Windows 10"
    },
    something = new {_else=294}
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: All I have is a dictionary, I don't know what is going to be on this dictionary, it could change to millions, billions even of combinations and items that could be on it, I can't write every single combination. I need something generic.

Comment: @seegal, OK I see. A JSON doc is basically a Dictionary<string, object>() where that object value could be another Dictionary<string, object>() - Key, Value store where value could be another Key, Value. I don't know if there is a ready lib that would parse your Dictionary from dots to that style. Probably not and it would take some effort to create one. (Maybe the code of an open source Key,Value database like Mongodb might help - they use C).